# Mule Twitter Maven Dependency - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mule.security.oauth.config.AbstractDevkitBasedDefinitionParser

Tags: mule

I am trying to use the Mule Twitter connector as a Maven dependency like follows:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-twitter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

But when I use "Run as Mule with Maven" or run a test from Maven I get the following error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mule.security.oauth.config.AbstractDevkitBasedDefinitionParser

Comment: What version of the mule runtime are you using?

Comment: 3.4. Just changed to 3.5-bighorn but still I have to add mule-module-devkit-support and mule-module-devkit-annotations and add them as inclusions on org.mule.tools maven plugin. Is this normal? I thought those dependencies would have been taken care of?

Comment: The cloudhub runtime (aka 3.5-bighorn) provides the mule-module-devkit-support jar. If you want to use the twitter module with an older version of mule you should use version 2.x